# SharpSVN - Is there a way to get a current working copy directly to a memory stream?

Tags: sharpsvn

I am using the latest version of SharpSVN.  I would like to retrieve the latest working copy of a repository, but I would like to load it into a memory stream instead of saving it to disk.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you plan to store directories and files in a memorystream? Or do you just want to get a file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SharpSVN how can you Export a file memory instead of to the filesystem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427075/using-sharpsvn-how-can-you-export-a-file-memory-instead-of-to-the-filesystem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want one file in memory?
(It is hard to stream directories in a memoryStream).

But with SvnClient.Write() you can just copy a Subversion url to a stream.